Is there convenient way to get a 'tight' autoscale in Swift Charts?
I am working with datasets whose minimum values are far from zero.  When I plot such data with Swift Charts, by default Swift Charts autoscales (using a nice-number algorithm) and gives me something that looks like this:

Since zero is always included, the data doesn't fill much of the window.  I will call this a "loose" autoscale.  What I would like is a "tight" autoscale, so the data is plotted more like this:

I can achieve this effect by keeping track of the minimum and maximum in my dataset and then simply add the chart modifier:
.chartYScale(domain: yMin...yMax)
As I add and drop data from my array I need to recalculate the min/max each time.  Is there some option in Swift Charts to do this "tight" autoscale automatically?  It would simplify parts of my code significantly.

It seems like default behaviour looks "bad" because it includes 0.
You can ask for an automatic Y scale that does not include 0:
.chartYScale(domain: .automatic(includesZero: false))

Minimal reproducible example:
struct Foo: Identifiable {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
    var id: Int { x }
}
let data = (0..<100).map { Foo(x: $0, y: Int.random(in: 40000..<50000)) }

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data) { datum in
            LineMark(x: .value("X", datum.x), y: .value("Y", datum.y))
        }
        // compare the result with and without this line
        .chartYScale(domain: .automatic(includesZero: false))
    }
}

